# org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Its been a week banging my head over this but still cannot seem to find a solution. I am using spring-data-neo4j maven artifact and the following lines of code which causes this issue:

```
/**
 * 
 */
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Transactional
public void addClassDescriptor(User user, ClassDescriptor classDescriptor) {
    Project project = user.getDefaultProject();
    ManagedFieldAccessorSet<ClassDescriptor> accessorSet = (ManagedFieldAccessorSet<ClassDescriptor>) project.getClassDescriptors();
    accessorSet.add(classDescriptor);
    /*
     * Save the user object after updating the set
     */
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

When executing the method it gives the following error at

> accessorSet.add(classDescriptor);

Stacktrace:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getResource(PersistenceManager.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.nodeCreate(PersistenceManager.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.createNode(NodeManager.java:270)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.createNode(EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.java:317)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.createNode(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.DelegatingGraphDatabase.createNode(DelegatingGraphDatabase.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityStateHandler.useOrCreateState(EntityStateHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:145)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.write(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:176)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:227)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:295)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.AbstractNodeRelationshipFieldAccessor.getOrCreateState(AbstractNodeRelationshipFieldAccessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.AbstractNodeRelationshipFieldAccessor.createSetOfTargetNodes(AbstractNodeRelationshipFieldAccessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.OneToNRelationshipFieldAccessorFactory$OneToNRelationshipFieldAccessor.setValue(OneToNRelationshipFieldAccessorFactory.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.updateValue(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.update(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.add(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:104)
```

My entities are as follows : ( User.java )

```
@GraphId
private Long id;

@RelatedTo(elementClass = Project.class)
@Fetch
private Set<Project> projects;
```

( Project.java )

```
    @GraphId
private Long id;
/**
 * 
 */
@RelatedTo(elementClass = ClassDescriptor.class)
@Fetch
private Set<ClassDescriptor> classDescriptors;

/**
 * 
 */
private boolean defaultProject;
```

Please help ! Attached is the dependency tree.

[image: Dependecy Tree]

Comment: What versions of SDN and Neo4j are you using? Could you past the output of `mvn dependency:tree` ?

Comment: I have attached the dependency tree for spring-data-neo4j. Please check

Comment: Abhi, how did you configure the transaction support in your application context and how do you get your bean with the method "addClassDescriptor" injected? If you use advanced mapping you don't need @Fetch

Answer (score 2):

I found when adding relations using a collection operation, as well as the @Transactional annotation you need to obtain a reference to the GraphDatabaseService and explicitly begin and end a transaction:

```
@Autowired
private GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

@Transactional
public void addRelation() {
  Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
  ...
  tx.success(); //or tx.failure();
  tx.finish();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the @Transactional annotation if you're explicitly starting and ending the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Abhi,

If it is happening consistently then I think you service is not a proper bean. How do you wire up your stuff?

Are you using simple or advanced mode (AspectJ)?

The stuff you have posted looks fine and simple, so I can't see why it wouldn't work...

Regards,

Lasse

Comment: I am using AspectJ.One clue could be - when I get the collection of projects it is an instance of LinkedHashSet but the instance of "classDescriptors" is ManagedFieldAccessorSet. Any idea why ? I think the solution to that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must protect the Transaction in a try chach...

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;


public class App {
    static Node firstNode = null;
    static GraphDatabaseService graphDb = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start ...");
        graphDb = ConnectNeo4j.initDB();
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try {
            firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
            firstNode.setProperty("message", "Es Geht!");
            System.out.println(firstNode.getProperty("message"));
            tx.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        tx.close();
        }
    }
}
```